# Visualforce Page (render as Excel) SOQL Limit Exceeds

Tags: visualforce, bulkification, excel

Here we want to generate Excel for Every record created/Edited of an sObject. Here we are using VF Page to generate an Excel and then store it in Documents/Attach File Object.
So the Flow looks like this after the Record is created or Edited.

1. AfterInsert/ AfterUpdate Trigger is Triggered which calls the Apex Trigger Handler Class
2. Apex Trigger Handler Class calls Vf page and also send Record Ids as a Paramter.
3. The VF Page Apex Controller get the record Ids paramter and Query the records to render them in VF Page
4. Than the Vf page Excel returned to the Apex handler class from where it is stored in the Documents/Attached files Object

Problem is when we Insert or Update record in bulk, for every record the vf page is called and every time a query from vf page controller has to be fired.

We tried to query data in bulk from the handler class itself and pass the record itself to vf page as paramter but the limit of the paramter gets exceeds.

Question is is there any other workaround for the above requirement?

[image: Attaching the Flow of the above Steps if it helps...]

Comment: What kind of limit do you hit? afaik, you can not call getContent from a trigger directly, then some async (queueable/future) is being used. What about passing multiple record ids to that async method in order to process few (not all or not 1) record in that job?

Comment: Why would you want to create an Excel voor every record of that SObject? Personally, every time someone asks for an Excel file with Salesforce data in it, I create a Salesforce report for them and give them the link to the report.

Comment: @kurunve SOQL Query Limit Exceeds

Comment: @SanderdeJong Actually It's not just a record, it's complex data with hierarchical, child and Parent related data with multiple conditions and the Excel has to be on each record's related attachment and files and also the data we retrieve is not possible with reports.